# fullPage.js Menu Does Not Appear As In Example

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I already imported js and css files of fullPage. This is the body:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="home"><a href="#main">Main</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="phonetics"><a href="#phonetics">Phonetics</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="search"><a href="#search">Search</a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="about"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        a
    </div>
    <div class="section"></div>
    <div class="section">c</div>
    <div class="section">d</div>
</div>
```

This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fullpage").fullpage({
        menu: "#menu",
        anchors:["main", "phonetics", "search", "about"],
        css3: true,
        loopBottom:false,
        loopTop:false,
        keyboardScrolling: false,
        sectionSelector: ".section",
        slideSelector: ".slide",

        /* http://www.colorcombos.com/color-schemes/14/ColorCombo14.html */
        sectionsColor: ["#443266", "#C3C3E5", "#F1F0FF", "#8C489F"]
    });
});
```

fullPage works great, but menu does not appear as in [example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/normalScroll.html). This is how menu looks like:

[image]

The things I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html-phonetics-library.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fullPage.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
```

Comment: in example if you have a look in dev tools you would find out that they have a stylesheet example.css which styles the menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fullPage works great, but menu does not appear as in example.

That's because **fullpage.js doesn't provide the styles for the menu**.
It is only there in the examples because the examples are using another stylesheet.

You are suppose to create your own menus and not just use the ones fullpage.js is using for the examples.

But if you really want to use its menu, take a look [at the examples stylesheet](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/master/examples/examples.css) or include it in your project by using the `examples.css` file used in [all the examples](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/master/examples).